How to get collaborator information from the ORCID API?
I am using the ORCID API to gather information relating to the works of multiple investigators. Most of the information is included in the .json output files but I'm missing the contributors section. I checked the sample files from their GitHub and contributor information is present.
Here's the contributor part of the .xml sample file from their GitHub page:
    <work:contributors>
        <work:contributor>
            <common:contributor-orcid>
                <common:uri>https://orcid.org/8888-8888-8888-8880</common:uri>
                <common:path>8888-8888-8888-8880</common:path>
                <common:host>orcid.org</common:host>
            </common:contributor-orcid>
            <work:credit-name>work:credit-name</work:credit-name>
            <work:contributor-email>work@contributor.email</work:contributor-email>
            <work:contributor-attributes>
                <work:contributor-sequence>first</work:contributor-sequence>
                <work:contributor-role>author</work:contributor-role>
            </work:contributor-attributes>
        </work:contributor>
    </work:contributors>
    <common:language-code>en</common:language-code>
    <common:country>AF</common:country>     

Here's the shell code I'm running to get the json files (I changed the real value of authtoken to my key and ORCID-ID for the investigator's ID):
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/orcid+xml' -H 'Authorization: Bearer authtoken' 'https://pub.orcid.org/v3.0/ORCID-ID/works' -i -o output.xml
Both the .xml and .json files are generated properly but they are missing contributor information.
Any advise on what could be the cause of this and a possible solution to the issue?
